# Remove slightly different duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The goal is to not show duplicate with slight differences. Here is an example:

I want to remove what is in green

[image]

This is the query I am currently using, but not quite accurate.

```
SELECT Package
FROM myTable
WHERE Package NOT IN (SELECT Package FROM myTable WHERE Package NOT LIKE '%_AC')
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Will the values always be suffixed with a value starting with an underscore (`_`)?

Comment: "not quite accurate" is a new synonym for "does not work" ?

Comment: `_` is the wild card for one single character.  There are several options to tell SQL Server that you actually want that character, and not to use it as a wild card, such as `NOT LIKE '%[_]AC'`.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: So when a row has a near duplicate, you want to remove both rows? Thats an unusual way to de-dup data.

Answer (score 1):

With just your sample data to go on you could try using a `not exists` criteria, such as

```
select * 
from t
where not exists (
    select * from t t2 
    where t.package like Concat(t2.package,'%')
    and t.package != t2.package
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas. If you have a unique column, you could use a `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT P
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.YourTable e
                  WHERE (YT.P LIKE e.P + '%'
                     OR  e.P LIKE YT.P + '%')
                    AND YT.ID != e.ID);
```

If not, then you could use a CTE and a windowed `COUNT`:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT YT1.*,
           COUNT(YT2.P) OVER (PARTITION BY YT1.P) AS C
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT1
         JOIN dbo.YourTable YT2 ON YT1.P LIKE YT2.P + '%'
                                OR YT2.P LIKE YT1.P + '%') --Will always JOIN to itself
SELECT P
FROM CTE
WHERE C = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc28dd6fa08c16fc33154fc377707636)